# How do I move worksheets in a workbook to two other open(newly created) workbooks based on two criteria Refer to the code below?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub transfersheets()
Dim originalwb As String, ws As Worksheet, wb1name As String, wb2name As String

originalwb = ThisWorkbook.Name

wb1name = Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("B2").Value & " " & "MD" & " " & "&" & " " & "Prime" & " " & "Rdg. Sht." & " " & "&" & " " & "Direct." & " " & UCase(Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")) & ".xlsx"
wb2name = Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("B2").Value & " " & "Non" & " " & "MD" & " " & "Rdg. Sht." & " " & "&" & " " & "Direct." & " " & UCase(Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy ")) & ".xlsx"

'Workbooks(originalwb).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Worksheet In Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets

'If Len(ws.Name) > 6 Then

    If Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "NMD*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).ws.Move Before:=Workbooks(wb2name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)


     ElseIf Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "PRIME*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).ws.Move Before:=Workbooks(wb1name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

     ElseIf Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "MD*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).ws.Move Before:=Workbooks(wb1name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    End If
'End If
Next
    Workbooks(wb1name).Save
    Workbooks(wb1name).Close


    Workbooks(wb2name).Save
    Workbooks(wb2name).Close

    Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("AA:AG").ClearContents

    MsgBox "The Reading Sheets & Direct Customers' Lists has  Been Successfully  Prepared."

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You already have code in there that moves worksheets from one workbook to another.  Are you getting an error?  You may want to format your questions a little better.

Comment: Yes . It keeps Returning an error from the line -          
Workbooks(originalwb).ws.Move Before:=Workbooks(wb2name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wbTarget

For Each ws In Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets

    If Len(ws.Name) > 6 Then

        If ws.Name Like "NMD*" Then
            Set wbTarget = Workbooks(wb2name)
        ElseIf ws.Name Like "PRIME*" Or ws.Name Like "MD*" Then
            Set wbTarget = Workbooks(wb1name)
        End If
        If Not wbTarget Is Nothing Then
            ws.Move Before:=wbTarget.Worksheets(wbTarget.Sheets.Count)
            Set wbTarget = Nothing
        End If       
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. it still didn't move the sheets to the requested workbooks.

Comment: OK - what *does* it do?  Any errors - anything at all?  Are your worksheets literally names "MD*" etc, or do you mean "begins with MD"?

Comment: They  begin with MD, PRIME NMD.

Comment: Thanks. still shows errors. "object variable or block variable not set " Runtime error 91 at the line - Set wbTarget = Workbooks(wb2name)

Comment: Then there's no open workbook with name `wb2name`.  Did you need to open it?

Comment: They  are open. In fact, even though the move doesn't work, the workbook files wb1name and wb2name are open at the background.

Comment: Are they open in the same instance of Excel though?

Comment: Yes they are. do they need to be activated ?

Comment: No, they don't need to be activated.  However if you're getting that error message it does indicate that there's a problem with the value of `wb2name`: try using `Debug.Print wb2name` and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Debug.Print wb2name returns correctly ( i.e the accurate workbook's name )

Comment: Hello, you didn't indicate the variable type for the wbtarget you adopted.

Comment: I left it as Variant, but adding `As Workbook` won't fix your problem.

Comment: With a few adjustments to some variables(including the Thisworkbook object), IT WORKED. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue.  I am using a for loop to loop through all the worksheets:

```
Sub transfersheets()

Dim originalwb As String, ws As Worksheet, wb1name As String, wb2name As String
originalwb = ThisWorkbook.Name

wb1name = Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("B2").Value & " " & "MD" & " " & "&" & " " & "Prime" & " " & "Rdg. Sht." & " " & "&" & " " & "Direct." & " " & UCase(Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")) & ".xlsx"
wb2name = Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("B2").Value & " " & "Non" & " " & "MD" & " " & "Rdg. Sht." & " " & "&" & " " & "Direct." & " " & UCase(Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy ")) & ".xlsx"

'Workbooks(originalwb).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets.Count

    If Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "NMD*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).Sheets(i).Move Before:=Workbooks(wb2name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)


     ElseIf Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "PRIME*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).Sheets(i).Move Before:=Workbooks(wb1name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

     ElseIf Len(Worksheet.Name) > 6 And Worksheet.Name = "MD*" Then
     Workbooks(originalwb).Sheets(i).Move Before:=Workbooks(wb1name).Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    End If
'End If
Next i
    Workbooks(wb1name).Save
    Workbooks(wb1name).Close


    Workbooks(wb2name).Save
    Workbooks(wb2name).Close

    Workbooks(originalwb).Worksheets("source").Range("AA:AG").ClearContents

    MsgBox "The Reading Sheets & Direct Customers' Lists has  Been Successfully  Prepared."

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. still shows errors. "object variable or block variable not set " Runtime error 91.

Comment: Is it still giving you that error on the same line?

Comment: Oh, and are your other workbooks open??? If they aren't actually open then you need to either leave them open while this is running or add code to open the workbooks before the loop starts.